# Complex numbers and their matrix form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, rotations

I have a line starting at the origin, and i extend it to a point $(a,b)$ in the plane.  This thing can be called a vector and be represented as $(a,b), [a\text{ }b]^T$ (column vector) or by $a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}$, where $(\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j})$ is the stardard basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$  Or it could be seen as a visual representation of a complex number where $(a,b)=a+bi,$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

So I want to rotate this vector $(a,b)$ $90$ degrees counter clockwise, so i know I can use my trusty matrix for rotations 
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(90) & -\sin(90) \\ \sin(90) & \cos(90)\\ \end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and we find that
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -b \\ a\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
Or, I could choose the complex multiplication way and say, 
$i(a+bi)=ai+bi^2=ai-b=-b+ai$

So we all know that, but what are some of the advantages and disadvantages to having two things that are completely identical operation in different systems?

Comment: For this particular example, one obvious difference is computation. To use the rotation matrix, you needed 4 trigonometric computations, 4 scalar multiplications and 2 additions. But in the other method, you swapped the entries and changed the sign of one. In general, for any degree of rotation, both will have same amount of computation.

Comment: Not clear what does the author mean. Multiplication of complex numbers gets two numbers (elements of the field ℂ) and yields a product from the same set. Euclidean 2-vectors are another thing. Although you can “multiply” two rotations and obtain another rotation, there is no multiplication on 2-vectors that gives 2-vectors.

Answer (score 4):

There is an **[isomorphism](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homeomorphism.html)** between the  *complex numbers*

$$
\color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b}i
$$

and the *rotation matrices*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a} & \color{red}{b} \\
 -\color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{a} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $\color{blue}{a}^{2} + \color{red}{b}^{2} = 1.$ We see the familiar [rotation matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html)
$$
R(\theta) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
 -\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which in the form
$$
x'=R(\theta)x
$$
rotates the $2$-vector $x$ about the origin by $\theta$, producing the $2$-vector $x'$.

---

**Verify isomorphism**

Start with two complex numbers $z_{1}$ and $z_{1}$. The Cartesian forms are
$$
 z_{1} = \color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b}i, \quad 
 z_{2} = \color{blue}{c} + \color{red}{d}i
$$
where the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, are all real. Blue numbers signify the real component of $z$, and red the imaginary component.
Equivalent matrix forms are defined as
$$
z_{1} = \left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a} & \color{red}{b} \\
 -\color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right),
\quad 
z_{2} = \left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{c}& \color{red}{d} \\
 - \color{red}{d} & \color{blue}{c}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Verify basic properties of the isomorphism.

**Addition**

$$
%
z_{1} +
z_{2} =
(\color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b}i) +
(\color{blue}{c} + \color{red}{d}i) 
=
(\color{blue}{a}+\color{blue}{c}) + (\color{red}{b} + \color{red}{d} )i 
$$

$$
%
z_{1} +
z_{2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a} & \color{red}{b} \\
 -\color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right) +
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{c} & \color{red}{d} \\
 -\color{red}{d} & \color{blue}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right) 
= \left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a}+\color{blue}{c}& \color{red}{b}+ \color{red}{d} \\
 -\color{red}{b}- \color{red}{d} & \color{blue}{a}+\color{blue}{c}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**Multiplication**

$$
z_{1} z_{2} =
(\color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b}i) 
(\color{blue}{c} + \color{red}{d}i) 
=
(\color{blue}{ac}- \color{red}{bd}) + 
(\color{red}{b}\color{blue}{c}+\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{d})i
%
$$

$$
%
z_{1} z_{2} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a} & \color{red}{b} \\
 -\color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{c} & \color{red}{d} \\
 -\color{red}{d} & \color{blue}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right) 
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{rc}
 \color{blue}{a}\color{blue}{c}- \color{red}{b}  \color{red}{d} & \color{red}{b}\color{blue}{c}+\color{blue}{a} \color{red}{d} \\
 - \color{red}{b} \color{blue}{c}-\color{blue}{a} \color{red}{d} & \color{blue}{a}\color{blue}{c}- \color{red}{b}  \color{red}{d} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**Inversion**

$$
%
\frac{1}{z} 
= \frac{1}{\color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b} i} 
= \left( \frac{\color{blue}{a} - \color{red}{b} i}{\color{blue}{a} - \color{red}{b} i} \right)
\frac{1}{\color{blue}{a} + \color{red}{b} i} 
= \left( \color{blue}{a}^{2} + \color{red}{b}^{2} \right)^{-1} \left( \color{blue}{a} - \color{red}{b} i \right) %
$$
$$
z^{-1} 
= \left(
\begin{array}{cr}
 \color{blue}{a} & - \color{red}{b}  \\
 \color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{a} \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1} 
= \frac{\text{adj }z}{\det z}
= \left( \color{blue}{a}^{2} + \color{red}{b}^{2} \right)^{-1}
\left(
\begin{array}{cr}
 \color{blue}{a} & \color{red}{b}  \\
 - \color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{a} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where adj $z$ is the adjugate matrix.

Comment: This is correct in the sense that these two topological spaces are homeomorphic, but what you (partially) justify in your answer is that these are *isomorphic as rings*. There is nothing in your answer which says anything about topology.

Comment: @Starfall: Excellent point; this is the site for mathematical precision and detail. We agree the answer falls short. Hopefully, it is enough for our poster. Thanks for paving the path to completion.

Comment: Isn’t the last matrix supposed to be $\left(
\begin{array}{cr}
 \color{blue}{a} &  \color{red}{b}  \\
- \color{red}{b} & \color{blue}{a} \\
\end{array}
\right)$?

Comment: It’s awkward that $R(\theta)$ is rotation through angle $-\theta$ rather than $\theta$. There was a misstatement early on. Somewhere in this post, OP was inconsistent with the choice of isomorphism.